# AudioKit V4.1 and Version 9.3 beta (9Q98q)

Tags: swift, audiokit, xcode9.3-beta

Trying to get a build to work with the latest beta of Xcode.

Has anyone had success?

I am getting an error with this:

```
@objc public protocol Aliased {
    associatedtype _Self = Self
}
```

"Associated type '_Self' cannot be declared inside '@objc' protocol 'Aliased'"

When building for iOS 11.0 or higher.

Suggestions:

Comment: Hi, In general we always say we don't support Xcode beta with AudioKit  and  AudioKit 4.1 itself is not out yet either. :) But we do appreciate you bringing this to our attention and it will give us a head start to address this before 9.3 comes out of beta and 4.1 (or 4.1.1 depending) will be released to make sure things continue to work as advertised.  I've alerted the person who actually created the _Self type and we'll geek out on a fix for this at NAMM today!

Comment: Thank you, this post was more for your information and to see if anyone had a "general solution" to this change in Swift. I am certain you will have a solution for us soon and I do appreciate your rapid response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed as of this commit: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/b31c2f22085dc00250416b1952b3af2f1e56c022

Thank you.